# \addvspace can't replace \vspace

Tags: macros, spacing, vertical-alignment

I want to replace `\vspace` with `\addvspace` in a command.  When so doing, I get obtuse "something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item."  errors.  I'd appreciate an explanation of why this happens and how to fix my `\fieldinfo` command (shown below) to use `\addvspace`.

I tried using `\protect\addvspace`, but that didn't work either.

Thanks for any help!

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tabularx}

% addvspace instead of vspace fails!
\newcommand{\fieldinfo}[2]{\addvspace{\baselineskip}\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{0.25in}X}%
        #1  &  #2 \\%
\end{tabularx} \\%
\addvspace{\baselineskip} \\ }%

\begin{document}
A, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi
tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris.

\fieldinfo{A}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris.}

\fieldinfo{B}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris.}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yor use of `\addvspace` fails because you are using it without being in vertical mode. Here's the definition of `\addvspace`:

```
\def\addvspace#1{%
  \ifvmode
    \if@minipage\else
      \ifdim \lastskip =\z@
        \vskip #1\relax
      \else
      \@tempskipb#1\relax
        \@xaddvskip
      \fi
    \fi
  \else
    \@noitemerr
  \fi}
```

as you can see, when not in vertical mode, `\@noitemrr` is called, which produces the error message "Something’s wrong--perhaps a missing \item".

To be able to use `\addvspace` you need to enter vmode, and this can be done, for example. by using `\par`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand{\fieldinfo}[2]{
  \addvspace{\baselineskip}
  \noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{0.25in}X}%
        #1  &  #2 \\%
\end{tabularx}%
\par\addvspace{\baselineskip}}%

\begin{document}
A, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi
tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris.

\fieldinfo{A}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris.}

\fieldinfo{B}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris.}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum.
\end{document}
```

Of course, you cannot use `\\` just after `\addvpace{\baselineskip}`

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo.  BTW, do you know why \addvspace throws the @noitemerr?  It's so confusing.  Isn't there a way to offer some useful message to users when writing macros like this?

Comment: @srking: that's how `\addvspace` is defined in the LaTeX kernel; you can see the original definition (which I included in my answer) in the Section 
**16.5 Vertical spacing** of the source2e document: http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf And yes, the error message could have been different and less confusing.

Answer (score 4):

The confusing error comes because you didn't use `\addvspace` in vertical mode. Try

```
\newcommand{\fieldinfo}[2]{\addvspace{\baselineskip}\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{0.25in}X}%
        #1  &  #2 \\%
\end{tabularx}\par
\addvspace{\baselineskip}}
```

That ends the paragraph and then adds the vspace afterward.