# Which are your "favourite" confusing error messages?

Tags: errors, big-list

This question: [\addvspace can't replace \vspace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14692/3954) shows a situation in which an error message can be confusing. If `\addvspace` is used when not in vmode the error message obtained is

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

which can be seen, for example, compiling the following simple example

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
a\addvspace{3em}
\end{document}
```

in this case, the error message is not really descriptive and could be misleading. The definition of `\addvspace` (Section 
**16.5 Vertical spacing** in `source2e`) explains what's going on:

```
\def\addvspace#1{%
  \ifvmode
    \if@minipage\else
      \ifdim \lastskip =\z@
        \vskip #1\relax
      \else
      \@tempskipb#1\relax
        \@xaddvskip
      \fi
    \fi
  \else
    \@noitemerr
  \fi}
```

so when \addvspace is used not in vmode, `\@noitemerr` is called producing the mentioned error message, as can be seeing in `lterror.dtx`.

```
\gdef\@noitemerr{%
<!autoload> \@latex@error{Something's wrong--perhaps a missing %
<!autoload> \protect\item}\@ehc}
<autoload> \@autoerr\@noitemerr}
```

Which other situations have you encountered in which the error message obtained seems confusing and (apparently) not related to the problem originating the error?

I would suggest to accompany each answer with the textual error message, a minimal example code producing the error, and a brief explanation of why that is the error message.

Comment: Package authors: make sure your package contains some amusing error messages.

Answer (score 35):

There are many, I prefer the ones with a bit of humor from TeX itself, my two favorites:

> Sorry, Pandora. (You sneaky devil.)

To trigger this message type:

```
\setbox0=\vbox{\halign{#\hfil\cr a\cr b\cr}}
\unhbox0
\bye
```

This will trigger an error `Incompatible list can't be unboxed`. Press 'h' for help and you will see the error.

and

> Pretend that you’re Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues

How to  trigger this message is left as an exercise for the reader. Clue is in the file `TEX.POOL`.

Comment: `\setbox0\vbox{}\unhbox0` is sufficient. The error message is wrong on two counts, though. It's not an `\hbox` that it is trying to unbox and TeX is perfectly happy to unbox an `\hbox` in vertical mode.

Comment: This question was revived by samcarter’s bounty; I’d like to add a couple of remarks.  1) “Sorry, Pandora…” is actually not an error message, but rather a help message.  2) About the remarks made by @TH., the help message is not wrong, since it says the TeX refuses “to unbox an `\hbox` in vertical mode *or vice versa*”; in this case, it has been asked to unbox a `\vbox` in horizontal mode (“vice versa”).  Indeed, it is not true that TeX happiliy `\unhbox`es a box (that’s the correct way to state what is happening) in vertical mode: it will switch to horizontal mode and *then* examine the box.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti is absolutely right. The `\unhbox` causes TeX to move to horizontal mode and a `\vbox` cannot be unboxed in horizontal mode. Everything about my comment was wrong. Sorry!

Comment: Is the Pandora one what became of the infamous ‘You can’t do that in horizontal mode’ in (I think) TeX78?

Answer (score 13):

Partially taken from the TeX FAQ entry [Capacity exceeded [semantic nest …]](http://texfaq.org/FAQ-semanticnest): The MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\silly{\hbox{here's \silly being executed}}
\silly% Be silly
\end{document}
```

produces the following error:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].
<to be read again> 
                   {
l.4 \silly
          
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.
```

Answer (score 3):

Does an infinite loop count as confusing error message?

In some early experiments with catcodes I tried the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\makeunderscoreactive}{\catcode`_=\active }
\newcommand{\makeunderscoreother}{\catcode`_=12\relax}
\makeunderscoreother
   \def\underscoreother{_}
\makeunderscoreactive
   \def_{\underscoreother}

\begin{document}
   \texttt{hello_world.txt} % this is fine
   $a_0$ % this causes an infinite loop
\end{document}
```

To be honest I am still not really sure why it's behaving that way.

Comment: So `_` is replaced by `\underscoreother` which is replaced by `_` which is replaced by ...

Comment: @MartinSchröder: There is something I’m still missing: the *active* `_` is replaced by `\underscoreother` that, in turn, is replaced by a “`\catcode 12`”-`_`; so why is this last character expanded again?

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Understood; LaTeX sets `\mathcode\`\_="8000` (file `fontmath.ltx`, l. 161), as plain TeX does.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti thanks, that explains it (in combination with [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109440/120953) which explains `\mathcode`).

Comment: @jakun: Exactly.  That’s why infinite recursion occurs only in math mode.  And of course, the `\mathcode` of an `_` of category 8 is not looked at, as that answer also explains.