# Documents with typical LaTeX errors

Tags: errors, big-list, tutorials

I am giving a LaTeX course and have the idea to let the students find and solve problems within a few documents. Basically they shall learn how to create minimal examples and read error messages.

However, currently I have no document with 'typical' errors around.

If someone has such examples from him- or herself or within this forum I would like to have the code or link. It does not matter if its short or long. It should just be enough to let the students play with it for some minutes.

Comment: One of the community polls on meta dealt with 'often made' errors. You can find it here: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1564/tex-community-polls/1587#1587

Comment: unfortunately that list is too special and has no examples. I was rather thinking about incompatible packages, missing braces, missing length, undefined controll sequences and such.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14739/which-are-your-favourite-confusing-error-messages/15261#15261 and offer a reward for the one that can hit the Hercules Poirot one, hehe... I see you having fun.

Comment: related blog post: http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/02/15/top-latex-mistakes/

Comment: In this case the counter `errorcontextlines` is very important.

Comment: A lot of LaTeX beginners fail to integrate math formulas into the embedding text. I think a question which helps to identify the problem would help here... but I fail to get a bad example. The common mistake is to use colons to separate formulas from the text.

Comment: Related question: [Opaque error messages given by common environments - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113745/opaque-error-messages-given-by-common-environments?rq=1)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Here is a list:

1. Using math-related content without specifying it explicitly as being math:

   ```
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
    Let's do \alpha and then \beta.
    \end{document}
   ```

   While the compiler may recover from this, the output doesn't resemble the expectation:

   [image]

   Moreover, TeX complains with the following - very typical - error:

   ```
    ! Missing $ inserted.
    <inserted text> 
                    $
    l.3 Let's do \alpha
                        and then \beta.
    I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
    you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
   ```

   <sub>To fix this error, explicitly introduce a switch to/from math mode by using `$`..`$` or `\(`..`\)` (for inline math content). That is, use `Let's do $\alpha$ and then $\beta$.`.</sub>
2. When intermixing text and math, some people use `\mbox` to box the text-related stuff. The reason here is that `\mbox` necessarily switches to text mode. So, if you have math content within `\mbox`, you need to explicitly restate its use. Here's a short example (causing a `Missing $ inserted` error):

   ```
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
    \[
      f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c, \mbox{where x \geq 0}
    \]
    \end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
   ```

   The symbol `\geq` requires math mode. Moreover, the spacing is off if the math content is not set in math mode (but that's typographic in nature).

   <sub>This error is fixed by using something like `\mbox{where $x\geq 0$}`. Better yet, the [`amsmath` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) provides `\text` which changes the text to the appropriate font style/shape based on its context while `\mbox` does not.</sub>
3. Code readability is encouraged, which is sometimes synonymous with leaving white space within your code. In the following elementary example, however, leaving (too much) white space causes an error (`Missing $ inserted`):

   ```
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
    \[

      f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c

    \]
    \end{document}​​​​​​​​​​
   ```

   (Sure, any one blank line removed in the above would also cause the problem. But it seems more hidden due to a symmetric blank line around the equation.)

   <sub>This can be avoided by either removing the blank lines, or introducing comment characters `%`. See [Blank lines in `align` environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10355/5764).</sub>
4. When typesetting regular delimiters, there is no need to match the pairs. For example, you can have expressions like `(a,b]` or even `|a,b`. However, when using extensible delimiters you need to define a pair using `\left` and `\right`. If you want to only use a single extensible delimiter, then you still have to define a paired delimiter using `.`, as in the following example:

   ```
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
    \[
      f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{@{}ll}
        ax^2 + bx + c, & x < 0 \\
        dx^2 + ex + f, & x \geq 0
      \end{array}
    \]
    \end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
   ```

   <sub>In the above example, even though no right delimiter is needed, it has to be specified using `\right.`.</sub>

   On that note, the following is also a common mistake leading to errors when delimiting using `{ }` (as in the above example - forgetting to escape `{`):

   ```
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
    \[
      f(x) = \left{\begin{array}{@{}ll}
        ax^2 + bx + c, & x < 0 \\
        dx^2 + ex + f, & x \geq 0
      \end{array}\right.
    \]
    \end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
   ```

   <sub>The correct usage is `\left\{`.</sub>

   Or, if you plan on using a notation like `]a,b[` (for whatever reason) and you want extensible delimiters, using `\right]` and then `\left[` just because the brackets face outward seems logical, but doesn't work:

   ```
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
    \[
      f(x) = \right]a,\frac{b}{c}\left[
    \]
    \end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
   ```

   <sub>Left delimiters use `\left` and right delimiters `\right`, regardless of the delimiter orientation.</sub>
5. Taken from the [TeX FAQ entry "No line here to end"](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-noline):

   It is definitely intuitive to use `\\` to cause a line break. And, this works in some cases. However, in other cases, LaTeX complains about the fact that `There's no line here to end`. The proposed complication is a purely unexpected line break on LaTeX's end.

   ```
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{description}
      \item[Very long label] \\
        Text...
    \end{description}
    \end{document}
   ```

   <sub>In the above example, the proposed quick-fix solution is to modify the line break `\\` to `\hspace*{\fill} \\`.</sub>

   Here is another example:

   ```
    \begin{center}
      First (heading) line \\ \\
      body of the centred text...
    \end{center}
   ```

   <sub>A solution is provided by modifying the double line breaks `\\` into a single line break with an optional length skip `\\[\baselineskip]`.</sub>
6. You are learning how to write macros or your own commands and try something like:

   ```
    \documentclass{article}
    \newcommand{\i}{$\iota$}% My macro: \i -> \iota
    \begin{document}
    This is \verb!\i!:~\i.
    \end{document}
   ```

   only to see LaTeX complain `Command \i already defined`. But you never defined it in any other way, how can it be defined already?! The reason is that the document class itself can define certain commands, just like any package that is loaded can define its own macros (and environments). Moreover, TeX also defines some macros by default (around 900 or so). Specific to this case, it is possible to see what `\i` was defined as previously and how to correct for this new definition using

   ```
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
    This is \verb!\i!:~\i. \par
    \renewcommand{\i}{$\iota$}% My macro: \i -> \iota
    This is \verb!\i!:~\i.
    \end{document}
   ```

   or one can use `\show\i` and inspect the `.log` file to see the "formal definition."

   <sub>Another solution, provided by LaTeX2e, is to use `\providecommand` rather than `\newcommand` or `\renewcommand`, since it has a built-in existence check. Or, one can use TeX's `\def` command which has a slightly different interface. However, use these with caution, since commands defined by packages or classes have specific meaning and redefinition without the knowledge of it could have disastrous consequences.</sub>
7. You find a snippet of LaTeX code online and wrap it into a minimal document:

   ```
    \documentclass{article}
    \newcommand{\my@macro}[1]{-#1-}% This is magic
    \begin{document}
    \my@macro{hi}
    \end{document}
   ```

   However, LaTeX is not happy and complains about `Missing \begin{document}`. Obviously it's there... so what's the problem? Well, the `@` symbol is a reserved when it comes to macro definitions and can't be used without some precaution.

   <sub>The category code for `@` needs to be changed in order for it to be used in a macro definition. Using `\makeatletter` will "make `@` have 'letter'/11 as a category code" so that it can be used. Usually, it is accompanied by a `\makeatother` counterpart, which "makes `@` have 'other'/12 as a category code".</sub>
8. You wish to define a *command* that does some formatting and decide to define a similarly-named *environment* that does the same thing, perhaps for the sake of convenience:

   ```
    \documentclass{article}
    \newcommand{\dosomething}[1]{\textbf{#1}}% Make argument bold
    \newenvironment{dosomething}{\bfseries}{}% Make contents bold
    \begin{document}
    \dosomething{test}
    \end{document}
   ```

   LaTeX complains that `Command \dosomething already defined` at `l.3 \newenvironment{dosomething}{\bfseries}{}` (line 3) even though you defined `\dosomething` only once (in line 2).

   <sub>The problem here is that when one uses `\newenvironment{myenv}{<beg env>}{<end env>}`, LaTeX defines two *commands* `\myenv` and `\endmyenv`, respectively using the `<beg env>` and `<end env>` definition. To correct for this, use unique names for commands and environments, even if they perform very similar tasks. For example, in the above case, define the *command* `\boldcmd` and *environment* `boldenv`, say.</sub>
9. You start playing around with graphics and would like to include a picture using the [`graphicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx):

   ```
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
    \usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
    \includegraphics{tiger}% Rooooaaaarrrrr!!!!!
    \end{document}
   ```

   but LaTeX complains that "Can be used only in preamble." This is not because of the use of `\includegraphics` (which is correct), but the required/included package (`graphicx`). The document structure requires certain "things" to be used only in certain places. In this case, you cannot load a package inside the `document` environment.

   <sub>Place `\usepackage{graphicx}` between `\documentclass{article}` and `\begin{document}` - the document *preamble*.</sub>
10. You're familiar with passing arguments to macros in the form

    [image]

    ```
    \textbf{Here is some \textit{text}.}
    ```

    Here `\textit` is passed as an argument to `\textbf`. However, you attempt to do the same with so-called verbatim content:

    ```
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
    \textbf{Here is some \verb|verbatim text|.}
    \end{document}​
    ```

    and receive the error "`\verb` illegal in command argument."

    <sub>`\verb` and friends are delicate and should be handled with care. It deals with the advanced topic of category codes and is perhaps best described in the TeX FAQ entry [Why doesn’t verbatim work within …?](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-verbwithin), together with appropriate solutions/alternatives. Most notably asking yourself the question whether using verbatim is actually necessary.</sub>
11. Someone advised you to use [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `align` environment after reading [`\eqnarray` vs `\align`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/5764) and requests a duplication of the [Taylor expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) of `\sqrt{1-x}`:

    [image]

    Ambitious in your attempt, you try:

    ```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
    \begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
      \sqrt{1+x} = 1 + x\left(\tfrac{1}{2} - \tfrac{1}{8}x + \tfrac{1}{16}x^2 
                   & - \tfrac{5}{128}x^3 \cdots \\
                   & + \tfrac{(-1)^i(2i)!}{(1-2i)(i!)^2(4i)}x^{i-1}\cdots\right)
    \end{align*}
    \end{document}
    ```

    (La)TeX spits out an error `Extra }, or forgotten \right`.

    <sub>`\left` and `\right` are delimiter counterparts and should always appear together and in the same (nested) group in math mode. In the above example, `\left` and `\right` are in different groups, not only spanning the `align` columns, but also rows. In instances like these, its much more convenient to use the separable `\Bigl` and `\Bigr` delimiter extenders. Alternatives also include using `\vphantom` to scale the separate groups vertically to the maximum size while using the null delimiters `\right.` and `\left.` where needed. See [`\left`/`\right` across multiline equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5612/5764).</sub>

12. Working with tables, you wish to insert some form of row labelling in the first column using a `[..]` style notation:

    ```
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
      Header row & Some content \\
      \hline
      [a] & Stuff A \\
      [b] & Stuff B
    \end{tabular}
    \end{document}​
    ```

    LaTeX complains about "Missing number, treated as zero" and "Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)". These errors are related to the optional argument that can be specified with the control sequence `\\`; `[b]` is considered to be the optional argument to `\\`, effectively trying to evaluate `\\[b]`, where `b` is expected to be a length/dimension. This is not the case, so it's substituted for zero (as the first error message reports), yet there is no dimension associated with it (as reported by the second error message). One reference to such an instance is given in [Allow `[` characters in tables without entering math-mode (from R)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124925/5764).

    <sub>The work-around here is to insert a non-`[` element at the appropriate location to avoid LaTeX from grabbing them as optional arguments to `\\`. For example `{}[b]` would do.</sub>
13. Experimenting with headers/footers, you attempt to stack some content in order to provide more information to the reader:

    ```
    \documentclass{article} 
    \usepackage{lipsum,fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{lipsum,fancyhdr}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage 

    My Name}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-5]
    \end{document}
    ```

    LaTeX complains about a

    ```
    Runaway argument?
    {\thepage 
    ! Paragraph ended before \f@ncyhf was complete.
    ```

    yet everything seems fine.

    This problem is partially related to (2), but stems from the fact that there are informally two different definition types in TeX: those that allow paragraph breaks, and those that don't. The former are macros defined using `\newcommand` or `\long\def` while the latter are those defined using `\newcommand*` or `\def`. As reference, see [What's the difference between `\newcommand` and `\newcommand*`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1050/5764)

    <sub>In order to get around this, don't use multiple paragraphs inside macros that can't handle them. This particular solution could be avoided using `\thepage \\ My Name` which technically sets a single paragraph. One could also use a `tabular` to provide the stacked look.</sub>
14. In an attempt to speed up your coding, you start using abbreviations for certain regularly-used constructions, like in the following minimal example:

    ```
    \documentclass{article}
    \newcommand{\bv}{\begin{verbatim}}
    \newcommand{\ev}{\end{verbatim}}
    \begin{document}
    Some regular text.
    \bv
    Some verbatim text.
    \ev
    \end{document}
    ```

    One would think that the replacement texts for `\bv` and `\ev` would be inserted in the input stream, yielding the expected output

    [image]

    <sub>In general, this works, as TeX merely inserts the replacement text of the given abbreviations into the input stream. Their replacement executions follow the expected syntax and everything works out fine.
    In some instances though, it doesn't. The above is one of them, although [there are others](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/285119/5764) [as well](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/171027/5764). This *feature* lies with the coding of the *environment* where it expects an *explicit* `\end{<env>}` form and scans until that is found. Follow the suggested work-around in the package documentation, if this exists. In other instances it's better to avoid the short hand altogether.</sub>

Comment: probably too late to be useful, but comments on two points: in 1, `\mbox` rigidly provides output in the current text size, while `\text` (requires `amsmath`) adjusts the size to the current environment.  in 5, another compelling argument for not redefining `\i` is the fact that `hyperref` will either "throw up" or override your definition since it redefines just about all one-letter commands as well as most "structural" commands like `\section`.  anyhow, very nice list.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Thanks, I've added your suggestion regarding (1). Even though you're correct about (5), I think as a beginner making "typical LaTeX errors," using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) might be a bit out of scope.

Comment: Re (4), be sure to teach your student not to do things like double line breaks unless it's *really* nessecary (i.e. use parsnip if that's what's intended, and so on).

Answer (score 16):

Why is the output of the two lines not identical?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\foo}{bar}

\begin{document}
bar bar

\foo \foo
\end{document}
```

You could also add a third line `\foo\foo`, but that might be too much of a clue.

---

Where is the output of the macro?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\begin{document}
\foo \foo

bar bar
\end{document}
```

---

This results in an error:

> Paragraph ended before \text@command was complete

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\begin{document}
\foo 

bar bar
\end{document}
```

---

TeX ignores extra spaces and newlines, so why does the output here change if the comment character `%` is removed?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{
    \textbf{#1}
}

\begin{document}
\foo{bar}%
bar bar
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please highlight how to solve the issue too :)

Comment: @damned: If you have a question about a specific one, please let me know, or just post a new question.  If something is not clear to you, I am sure there are others with the same question.

Comment: @PeterGrill can you please explain, why the error in the 2nd case occurs and how to fix it?

Comment: @Max: In the second example, the macro `\foo` is expecting a madatory parameter. So, to fix it make sure you provide the required parameter.  I am not sure I can properly explain what is going on, so perhaps you should post a new question about how not providing a parameter results in no output or error messages.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Thanks, but i could already solve the problem on my own. I had the same error message, but without the mandatory parameter. The reason was i just forgot a } once and i didn't see it for quite a while.....

Answer (score 10):

two *different* kind of errors with the same error message

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

foo \textt{bar} baz
\rotatebox{45}{45}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Leslie Lamport's *LaTeX: A Document Preparation System* provides a list of common errors. (Same for [*LaTeX and Friends*](http://www.springer.com/computer/media+design/book/978-3-642-23815-4)---it will be available by the end of January.) Another list may be found at the [TeX FAQ](https://texfaq.org/) (look for *The Joy of TeX Errors*).

**Bibliography**

```
@Book{Lamport:94,
  author     = {Lamport, Leslie},
  title      = {\LaTeX: A Document Preparation System},
  year       = {1994},
  isbn       = {0-021-52983-1},
  publisher  = {\Range{Addison}{Wesley}},
}

@Book{vanDongen:2012,
  author    = {van~Dongen, M.\,R.\,C.},
  title     = {{\LaTeX} and Friends},
  publisher = {Springer},
  year      = {2012},
  isbn      = {978-3-642-23815-4},
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I got interesting errors when inserting text from Microsoft Word into LaTeX. Especially characters sch as "-" are encoded differently in Word than in TeXniccenter. Finding those errors is always tedious.

Comment: If you have a reasonable editor, these errors aren't too difficult.  For example, when saving a file with UTF-8 characters as ASCII, *Emacs* will pause to ask you whether to save as UTF-8 instead, giving you time to click on the provided links (or write a keyboard macro) to replace these characters with their TeX-friendly equivalents.  (I'm *sure* I've seen this functionality out of TeXmaker, so it likely exists in TeXnicCenter as well.)  (Also, I'm not really sure these are actual LaTeX errors --- it's more of an encoding nightmare.)

Comment: Encoding nightmare is about right: It's quite common to have a few characters in the pasted text, like Word's infamous directed quotes, which are silently dropped by TeX. They often look fine in my LaTeX editor, and I only notice when I look at my formatted document carefully. It's a little OT but it's worth mentioning...

Comment: Actually some of these punctuation-like charactersused by MS-Word are not defined in the file loaded by `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. You can nevertheless add then by using the command `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2013}{\textendash}` or more easely with `newunicodechar` package with `\newunicodechar{-}{--}`

Answer (score 2):

Writing reserved characters without escaping them. The most common to myself, especially at first, was the underscore ______ and the Dollar sign $.  The percent % also.  Of all of these I think the underscore when not escaped gives the weirdest output.