# No \makeatletter required?

Tags: macros, tex-core, catcodes

In typing up some small examples that might create errors in LaTeX (for [Documents with typical LaTeX errors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33468/5764)), I tried the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\my@macro#1{-#1-}% This is magic
\begin{document}
\my@macro{hi}% Print -hi-
\end{document}
```

Since I almost religiously encompass `@`-symbol definitions and/or usage with `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` (see [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/5764)), and since [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx) issues `\makeatother` at literally the 4th-to-last line, I thought this would flash an error.

It didn't.

Not only was I able to define the macro, I was able to use it without problem after it is defined. Why is this the case?

One clue here, although I don't know why, is that I'm using the TeX `\def` syntax, rather than `\newcommand`, which *does* produce an error.

Comment: Jep thats true. (pdflatex utd) When i add a `@` somewhere between `begin/end {document}` it gets printed. So in fact it seems to be a letter. Maybe a change in pdflatex?

Comment: @bloodworks nope `@` is not a letter but a symbol just like `1` or `/` etc. And yes symbols print but they can't be used in macros "names". they can however be used inargument delimiters when using `\def` to define macros.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Your definition defines a macro `\my` that is required to be followed by `@macro` followed by one argument (which is either a single token or a brace group). Thus this gives you the result.

Reason that this works this way is that normally `@` is not a letter (but a symbol which is `\catcode` 12) so it would end the "macro name" but it then becomes part of the parameter text which is everything that is follows after the name up to the `{` which starts the replacement text. You can test this as follows:

```
\show\my
\my @macro {hi}  % should work too
\my {hi}         % error
```

LaTeX 's `\newcommand` complains as it builds up the macro definition differently and doesn't allow for delimited arguments.

Answer (score 36):

You are defining the control sequence `\my` which has a bizarre `<parameter text>` consisting of the tokens

> @<sub>12</sub> m<sub>11</sub> a<sub>11</sub> c<sub>11</sub> r<sub>11</sub> o<sub>11</sub> #1

(as subscripts I've put the category code).

This means that `\my` *must* be followed by `@macro` and then comes the argument.

You can experiment writing, after `\begin{document}`,

```
\my @macro{hi}
\def\my@differentmacro#1{#1!}
\my@differentmacro{Uh}
\my@macro{ERROR}
```

The first line will be accepted and print

> -hi-

because spaces after control sequence names are always ignored.

The second line will be accepted and perform the requested definition; the third line will print

> Uh!

while the fourth will give an error:

```
! Use of \my doesn't match its definition.
```

Indeed `\my` now requires `@differentmacro` after it.

What's the business? If the category code of `@` is 12 (`\makeatother`), then the scanner during `\def\my@macro#1{-#1-}` will stop the control sequence name as soon as it finds `@` which is a non letter (letters have category code 11), so it takes everything up to the first brace as the `<parameter text>`.

When `\makeatletter` is in force, `@` *is* a letter, so with

```
\def\my@macro#1{-#1-}
```

the macro's name will be `\my@macro` and the parameter text will be simply `#1`.

Comment: +1 for the example with `\my@differentmacro`. That was what got me to understand how this works.