# The different meanings of LaTeX's \stop command

Tags: parsing, meaning

we know that

```
\stop
```

will cause LaTeX to stop parsing and output what it has processed up to this command.

But then I discovered another way to use it, as demonstrated in this minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
  \def\demo#1-#2\stop{#2}
\begin{document}
  \def\sample{foo-bar}
  \expandafter\demo\sample\stop
  There's the Word 'bar' above this text and
  this made it into the output despite a stopping command.
\end{document}
```

How is `\stop` used here and why didn't it actually interrupt the LaTeX?

Comment: Related: [No `\makeatletter` required?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40300/5764) In that post, the `@` is also used as a delimiter token.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The meaning of `\stop` is never actually read in the above.  It is just used as a delimiter token.  In this situation, absolutely anything will do:

```
\documentclass{article}
  \def\demo#1-#2\StopInTheNameOfTeX{#2}
\begin{document}
  \def\sample{foo-bar}
  \expandafter\demo\sample\StopInTheNameOfTeX
  There's the Word 'bar' above this text and
  this made it into the output despite a stopping command.
\end{document}
```

A simple `\show\StopInTheNameOfTeX` shows that this has no meaning, but in this context that meaningless is itself meaningless.

Comment: D'Oh, so much for good choice of token names ... and kudos for `\StopInTheNameOfTeX`

Answer (score 10):

You are defining a macro with delimited argument, something that the primitive commands `\def`, `\gdef`, `\edef` and `\xdef` can do, but `\newcommand` can't.

Let's see:

```
\def\demo#1-#2\stop{#2}
```

The *parameter text* consists of the following tokens

```
#1 • - • #2 • \stop
```

Here I use • just to separate the tokens and the spaces are for readability; in the context of the parameter text it's common to consider `#1` as just one token.

This means that the first argument to `\demo` will be all that comes after `\demo` up to (and not including) the first `-` token at the same brace level; the second argument will be all after that `-` up to (and not including) `\stop`, again at the same brace level. So, if the call is

```
\demo 1{2-3}4-5\stop
```

TeX will set `#1 <- 1{2-3}4` and `#2 <- 5`

The meaning of the delimiter tokens is *never* looked at when `\demo` is expanded: TeX just matches the pattern, taking the shortest match. For instance, with

```
\demo--\stop
```

we'll have an empty `#1` and `#2` will be changed into `-`.

You can even use an undefined token as delimiter:

```
\def\demo#1-#2\nobodydarestodefinethistoken{#2}
```

and TeX won't complain: the pattern is matched, parameters are substituted with the found arguments and the tokens used for the match will be discarded.

---

There is one exception: the left brace that starts the replacement text can be used also as a delimiter with a peculiar syntax: if you say

```
\def\demo#1-#2#{#2}
```

and then

```
\demo ABC-DEF{}
```

the second argument will be `DEF` and the left brace that *must* follow will not be discarded.