# Non-alphabet letter in \csname ...\endcsname

Tags: tex-core

Why can't I get what I want in the following code?
MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
%
\def\aaa*{*}
\def\aaaAAA{AAA}
|\csname aaaAAA\endcsname|% typeset |AAA| as I desired.
|\csname aaa*\endcsname|% I want to get |*|, but get ||. So, what's wrong with my code?
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\def\aaa*{*}` does not define a macro called `\aaa*`. It defines a macro called `\aaa` that must always be followed by a `*`. `|\csname aaa\endcsname*|` would give you the output of `\aaa*`. To define `\aaa*` you need `\expandafter\def\csname aaa*\endcsname{*}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because `\csname aaa*\endcsname` does not exist and therefore defaults to `\relax` which typesets nothing. Why does it not exist? Well, the problem is similar to [No `\makeatletter` required?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40300/5764):

In `\def\aaa*{*}`, `*` does not form part of the definition, but instead forms part of the *parameter* text used. In order to define a macro to include a `*` in the definition *name* you'll have to use

```
\expandafter\def\csname aaa*\endcsname{*}% Similar to \@namedef{aaa*}{*}
```

Answer (score 9):

Consider the following example

```
\def\aaa*{*}

\show\aaa*
```

Running TeX on it (any flavor), will report as follows on the console

```
> \aaa=macro:
*->*.
l.3 \show\aaa
             *
?
```

How do we read it? The primitive command `\show` reports the meaning of the following token; the to lines before the question mark tell us that `\aaa*` are *two* tokens, because `*` appears in the continuation line.

TeX is also telling us that `\aaa` is a macro that has a nonempty parameter text (what's reported before `->`) consisting of an asterisk. In other words, `\def\aaa*{*}` instructs TeX that `\aaa` *must* be followed by `*` and the two tokens will be replaced by `*`.

For instance, you can call it also as

```
\aaa *
```

because the space after `\aaa` is ignored when building tokens from input.

If you want to use `\csname`, then it should be

```
\csname aaa\endcsname *
```

(the space before `*` is optional).

In case you're wondering how *-variants are implemented in LaTeX, here it is:

```
\newcommand{\foo}{\@ifstar\foostar\foonostar}
\newcommand{\foostar}{<what we want \foo* to do>}
\newcommand{\foonostar}{<what we want \foo to do>}
```

Possible arguments have to be grabbed by `\foostar` or `\foonostar`, depending on the desired syntax.

The approach with `xparse` is slightly different, but the command will not have the `*` as part of the name nonetheless.

Comment: Thank you so much for these detail explanations