# Newlines after section headings in amsart

Tags: sectioning, line-breaking, amsart

This latex code:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{amsart}

\begin{document}
  \subsubsection*{Animals}
  Rabbit horse monkey cow
\end{document}
```

Generates something that looks approximately like this:

> *Animals*. Rabbit horse monkey cow.

I'd like to add a newline after the section heading, but if I use `\\` with

```
\subsubsection*{Animals}\
```

I get:

> ! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

If I put the `\\` inside the brackets, with Animals, then I get a newline but it separates "Animals" from the period:

> Animals
>
> . Rabbit horse monkey cow.

How can I put a newline after the section heading without separating it from the period?

EDIT: A good solution is provided below using redefinition of \subsubsection, but a simpler method is to do

```
\subsubsection*{Animals}\hspace*{\fill} \\
Rabbit horse monkey cow.
```

Comment: Trying to break lines with \\ is a common mis-use of line-breaking. See [Documents with typical LaTeX errors](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33472/5764).

Comment: you can put something typesettable but invisible after the subsubsection heading; `$ $` does nicely.  i can't recommend `titlesec` because it's an option we don't permit when a paper is submitted to an ams journal, so we've never tested it.  (for the same reason, i can't "unrecommend" it either.  for whatever it's worth, it has never been identified as causing failures with `amsart`; just "not tested here".)

Comment: @barbarabeeton since I added to my initial answer an option using `titlesec`, I took the liberty to quote you; I hope it's OK.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina -- yes, it's okay, and i appreciate the recognition that publishers do have guidelines, and would really like it if authors actually read (and follow) the instructions.  thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can redefine `\subsubsection` appropriately; here's the original definition in amsart.cls

```
\def\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}%
  \z@{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{-.5em}%
  {\normalfont\itshape}}
```

and you can redefine it using something like this:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}    

\makeatletter
\def\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}%
  \z@{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{.1\linespacing}%
  {\normalfont\itshape}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\subsubsection*{Animals}
Rabbit horse monkey cow
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option, not requiring knowing the inner definition of `\subsubsection`, is to use the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{0ex plus .2ex}

\begin{document}
\subsubsection*{Animals}
Rabbit horse monkey cow
\end{document}
```

However, if you are writing a paper for a submission to an AMS journal, pay attention to the following warning from **barbara beeton** regarding the use of `titlesec` with the AMS document classes:

> i can't recommend `titlesec` because it's an option we don't permit
>   when a paper is submitted to an ams journal, so we've never tested it.
>   (for the same reason, i can't "unrecommend" it either. for whatever
>   it's worth, it has never been identified as causing failures with
>   `amsart`; just "not tested here".)

Comment: As reference for more information on what the elements in `\@startsection` means, see [Where can I find help files or documentation for commands like `\@startsection` for LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31795/5764)

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo, good response.  Looks like I need to teach myself some lessons on redefinition and \@startsection.  @Werner: helpful link!

Comment: So, following your first idea, what should be the parameter to be modified in order to get that final period that was included before at the end of the section heading?

Answer (score 17):

A simple workaround not requiring any modification.

If you directly put `\\` then it tells you there is no line here to end, but if you put any character before `\\` it will allow you to create a new line.

So my workaround is put a `~` right after the `\subsubsection{tittle}`, and `\\` after `~`, the `~` create an invisible space after your title, and which enables you to create a new line for your visible paragraphs.

Answer (score 10):

The simplest way would be to give `subsubsection` some invisible text before the newline:

```
subsubsection*{Animals}~\\Rabbit horse monkey cow
```

You may choose `\mbox{}` instead of `~`.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply add `\hfill` at the end of the `\subsubsection{}` like so

```
\subsubsection{Something}\hfill
```

Comment: The above does not work. TL 2022

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fine tune the spacing after the linebreak then you can use an invisible rule e.g. `\subsection{Animals}\rule[-10pt]{0pt}{10pt}\\`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In general a full compilable answer is to favour just like MWEs in the questions.

Answer (score 0):

Using hfill with an empty new line works for me.

```
\subsubsection{myTitle}
\hfill

My paragraph. My paragraph. My paragraph. My paragraph. My paragraph.
```