# Help me fix "Underfull \hbox" warning

Tags: line-breaking, warnings

I meet the trouble with an "Underfull `\hbox`" warning with this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,final]{book}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\author{Phuong}
\title{Đáp áp Bộ đề ôn tập học kỳ I khối 11 năm 2011-2012}
\def\labelitemi{Câu}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\textbf{ĐỀ 1}
\end{center}
\newcounter{qcounter}
\begin{list}{Câu \Roman{qcounter}: \\}{\usecounter{qcounter}}
\item \hspace*{\fill} \\
    \begin{enumerate}
    \setcounter{enumi}{0}
    \item~ Tìm tập xác định của hảm số $y = \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos{x}}{2+\sin{x}}}$
    \item~ Giải các phương trình sau:\hspace*{\fill} \\
    \end{enumerate}
\end{list}

\end{document}
```

The warning appears for the line:

```
\item \hspace*{\fill} \
```

Please help me avoid this warning.

Comment: Related content on UK TeX FAQ: [No line here to end](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=noline), as well as [Documents with typical LaTeX errors](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33468/5764)

Answer (score 5):

You're forcing new lines where you don't need to force them at lines 19 and 24 of your code.  I removed them and there are no more errors.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,final]{book}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\author{Phuong}
\title{Đáp áp Bộ đề ôn tập học kỳ I khối 11 năm 2011-2012}
\def\labelitemi{Câu}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\textbf{ĐỀ 1}
\end{center}
\newcounter{qcounter}
\begin{list}{Câu \Roman{qcounter}: \\}{\usecounter{qcounter}}
\item \hspace*{\fill}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \setcounter{enumi}{0}
    \item~ Tìm tập xác định của hảm số $y = \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos{x}}{2+\sin{x}}}$
    \item~ Giải các phương trình sau:\hspace*{\fill} 
    \end{enumerate}
\end{list}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm quite dubious about the ``\\`` after `\Roman{qcounter}`; instead of `\hspace*{\fill}`, `\mbox{}` is simpler.

Comment: I just want break line after each item.