# Allow [ characters in tables without entering math-mode (from R)

Tags: tables, math-mode, r

I have R code that produces latex code like:

```
\begin{tabular}{D{.}{.}{7}D{.}{.}{7}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{x} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{y} \\
\midrule
[1, 5) &  1 \\
[1, 5) &  2 \\
[5, 8) &  5 \\
[5, 8) &  7 \\
[8,10] &  8 \\
[8,10] & 10 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

And this is producing math errors:

```
! LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter.
```

How do I prevent this from happening? I'd like the square brackets to be printed as-is since they represent intervals - previously in the office a workaround of switching to a { has been done but it looks terrible!

I've read around but not seen anything specific about preventing latex from entering math-mode.  However, I'm new to this so I'm probably using the wrong keywords!

**Example**

I'm producing the code inside knitr chunks with the following parameters:

```
<<tab-example,echo=FALSE,cache=FALSE,results='asis'>>=
example<-data.frame(cbind(x=1:10,y=1:10))
example$x<-cut(example$x,3)
toLatex(example)
@
```

**Packages currently used**

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr,dcolumn,booktabs,float,titlesec}
\usepackage[margin=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage[us,12hr]{datetime}
```

Comment: a square bracket after `\\` in a `tabular` is always assumed to indicate a dimension.  if you are instead presenting data, always wrap the bracketed expression in braces to avoid misinterpretation.

Comment: Are you able to group (surround by braces `{..}`) the ranges or insert something *before* the first `[` on every line? LaTeX gets confused, expecting a length if you follow ``\\`` by `[`.

Comment: So simply adding in the code for a space?

Comment: @StephLocke: Yes, or you could add `{}` before each element.

Comment: Thank you both very much!  So simple but `{}` really did the trick.  If you'd like to put it as an answer I'll mark it as accepted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your use of (snippet)

```
%...
[1, 5) &  2 \\
[5, 8) &  5 \\
%...
```

is interpreted (visually) as

```
%...
       &  1 \\[1, 5) 
       &  2 \\[5, 8)
       &  5 \\[5, 8)
%...
```

since LaTeX expects an optional argument after `\\` to contain a length/dimension. The easiest work-around is to insert a non-`[` after `\\`, like `{}` (an empty group). For example:

```
\begin{tabular}{D{.}{.}{7}D{.}{.}{7}}
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{x} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{y} \\
  \midrule
  {}[1, 5) &  1 \\
  {}[1, 5) &  2 \\
  {}[5, 8) &  5 \\
  {}[5, 8) &  7 \\
  {}[8,10] &  8 \\
  {}[8,10] & 10 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

<sub>The first `{}` is not needed, but I've inserted it for a consistent look in the code.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

As a follow up to @Werner's excellent explanation, as I was using R I created a `sanitise` function to use instead of the default `xtable::sanitize` function that escapes these appropriately.

The package [optiRum](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/optiRum/) can be downloaded for the `sanitise` function to be used.