# About \def\b*{\begin{align*}}

Tags: math-mode, macros, amsmath

I want to make the code shorter. I defined the following pair of macros:

```
\def\b*{\begin{align*}}
\def\e*{\end{align*}}
```

My point is that I saw this in a document, with

```
\def\b*{\begin{eqnarray*}}
\def\e*{\end{eqnarray*}}
```

instead. The first pair of macros do not compile (on sharelatex.com),
and the second one does. Why?

Comment: This is a documented restriction of the ams alignments, the `\end` needs to be explicit Also why the `*` ?

Comment: Are you not using an editor with auto-completion?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: the * was in the original document I found. Is there any way to get what I want (define a macro and avoid equnarray?)

Comment: @Sigur: I do, but I prefer having a shorter code (I really like the code in which I found the macro).

Comment: `\def\b*` defines `\b` not `\b*` (but defines it to require a `*`) amsmath is open source so you can change anything but basically no, it is not intended that you hide the environment syntax.

Comment: The first line is missing a `}`. Did that happen when writing this post?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: there is no missing } in my code, but thanks.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: thank you for your answer. Do you have a source explaining this kind of limitation?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [`technote`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/technote.pdf) document explains why this kind of shorthand definitions will fail:

> ### 6   Why can’t I use abbreviations for `\begin{align} ... \end{align}`?
>
> Authors often like to use abbreviations such as `\beq` `\eeq` for `\begin{equation}` `\end{equation}`. For some environments defined by the `amsmath` package, such as `align`, `gather`, `multline`, and others of the same general type, this does not work: An attempt to define `\bal` `\eal` as shorthand for `\begin{align}` `\end{align}` will fail with a puzzling error message. This has to do with unfortunately nontrivial technical complications: the given environments must read their contents as a delimited macro argument because they do multipass processing of the contents using algorithms inherited from Spivak’s `amstex.tex`. The obvious solution-substitution of different algorithms that do box shuffling instead of token shuffling for the multipass calculations-would require rewriting these display environments from the ground up; while that is a worthy goal, it was beyond the original scope of the AMS-LaTeX project. Work is under way on an auxiliary package called `breqn` that addresses not only this problem but a number of others; at the time of this writing, however [September 1999] it has only progressed as far as a beta release.
>
> Some workarounds:
>
> - `\def\bal#1\eal{\begin{align}#1\end{align}}`
> - Define `\newcommand{\env}[2]{\begin{#1}#2\end{#1}}` and then use
>   `\env{align}{...}`

Comment: +1 for superior line-breaking over David's answer. `;)`

Comment: Nice! Is there any chance to get it allowed in the future?

Comment: @Sigur I'm afraid that is a question for the AMS team. **barbara beeton** could surely provide an informed answer for your question (but I strongly suspect that the answer will be "no").

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, me too. `:-)`

Comment: @Sigur -- yes, the answer is "no".  if *real* bugs aren't addressed in a timely manner, what do *you* think is the likelihood of a major design change being undertaken?

Comment: @Werner after your last edit, Sean Allred's comment is no longer fun (or even understandable) :-)

Comment: For those interested, view the [original post in the revision history](http://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/171029/1)...

Answer (score 8):

The restriction of the AMS alignments that they may not be hidden behind command forms is documented on page 28 of the amsmath guide (`texdoc amsmath` ) Actually the restriction is better described in the technical notes (`texdoc technote`) as shown in the other answer.

The names chosen here are particularly dangerous as using `\def` you lose the warning that you would have had from the correct LaTeX syntax `\newcommand` that you were over-writing the standard accent command `\b`.

Comment: Perhaps you could include the link to the `technote` document (perhaps even the image) in your answer so I can delete mine?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I thought it was in technote but I typed `texdoc texnotes` with an s and got a different document, so I made do with the reference in amsmath guide:-)  Leave your answer and I'll cross link:-)