# How do I use \begin{equation}

Tags: math-mode

I'm trying to enumerate my equations using this command:

```
\begin{equation}

w(H)\le (g^2-5g+10)/2

\end{equation}
```

I have this in the log:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.1026 \end{equation}
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
! Display math should end with $$.
<to be read again>
\endgroup
l.1026 \end{equation}
The `$' that I just saw supposedly matches a previous `$$'.
So I shall assume that you typed `$$' both times.
[21]...
```

I've already tried to put this $$ or $$$$ and nothing happens.

I need help.

Thanks

Comment: Don't leave blank lines and… why the `$$` at the end of the line?

Comment: There should be no blank line inside an `equation` environment.

Comment: @Manuel thanks do you know how I can enumerate by sections, for example (3.2) instead of (2) in the chapter 3?

Comment: @egreg thanks egreg, do you know how I can enumerate the equations by sections? thanks again.

Comment: If you have `\usepackage{amsmath}` (and you should anyway), just add `\numberwithin{equation}{section}` just before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Don't leave a blank line inside your `equation`. See [Documents with typical LaTeX errors](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33468/5764).

Comment: @Werner thank you for this tutorial, I'm reading it right now.