# When is verbatim content absolutely necessary?

Tags: verbatim

Item 9 of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33472/17423) to [Documents with typical LaTeX errors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33468/17423) says:

> `\verb` and friends are delicate and should be handled with care. It deals with the advanced topic of category codes and is perhaps best described in the TeX FAQ entry [Why doesn’t verbatim work within …?](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-verbwithin), together with appropriate solutions/alternatives. Most notably asking yourself the question whether using verbatim is actually necessary.

To be honest, most of my use for `\verb` is just a shortcut to make all the necessary catcode changes and switch to `\ttfamily`, which seems like it could be done with a 'simpler' macro. What makes `\verb` special?

Comment: `\verb` (or simpler variations thereof) is necessary when you want to typeset TeX's special characters without changing the code by adding markup (macros, `\string`, escape character and so on).

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several cases where `\verb` can be dispensed with.

Suppose you're writing the manual for a package and you want to typeset command or environment names; then a couple of definitions such as

```
\newcommand\cs[1]{\texttt{\string#1}}
\newcommand\env[1]{\texttt{\string\begin\string{#1\string}}}
```

will do. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareRobustCommand\cs[1]{\texttt{\string#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\env[1]{\texttt{\string\begin\string{#1\string}}}

\begin{document}

\section{\cs{\foo} and \env{baz}}

We describe the command \cs{\foo} and the environment \env{baz}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, both `\cs` and `\env` can be used in a section title, but you'll soon discover that `\cs` doesn't really work in a title and a more complicated definition is needed:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\cs[1]{%
  \ifx\protect\@typeset@protect
    \texttt{\string#1}%
  \else
    \string\cs{\noexpand\string\string#1}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

so that the `.aux` file will have the correct annotation

```
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}\cs{\foo} and \env  {baz}}{1}}
```

Often this is simplified by avoiding the backslash in the argument:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\cs[1]{\texttt{\symbol{`\\}#1}}
```

but the input would be

```
We describe the command \cs{foo} and the environment \env{baz}.
```

This is the approach taken by `ltugboat.cls` which has

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\cs}[1]{{\tt \char`\\#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\tubbraced}[1]{\mbox{\texttt{\char`\{#1\char`\}}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\env}[1]{\cs{begin}\tubbraced{#1}}
```

(yes, with `\tt`, I hope they'll change this some day).

Package manuals also need other features for explaining the syntax of commands. So, for instance, one must do something like

```
\cs{\foo}\oarg{optarg}\marg{arg}
```

after defining `\oarg` and `\marg` in a suitable way. Substituting this with

```
\verb|\foo[optarg]{arg}|
```

would lose the emphasis on the “metavariables”. Entering and exiting from verbatim mode is clumsier

```
\verb|\foo[|optarg\verb|]{|arg\verb|}|
```

and the `\marg` approach allows to format the metavariables as we like.

Are there places where `\verb` or `verbatim` are *necessary*? Anything that can be done with `\verb` or `verbatim` can be obtained with suitable macros, but at the expense of markup. If I want to describe the code in `ltugboat.cls` for remarking the bad usage of `\tt`, should I type

```
\begin{verbatim}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\cs}[1]{{\tt \char`\\#1}}
\end{verbatim}
```

or

```
\begin{flushleft}\ttfamily
\string\DeclareRobustCommand\string{%
\string\cs\string}[1]\string{\string{%
\string\tt\space\string\char`\string\\\string#1%
\string}\string}
\end{flushleft}
```

that would give the same output?

[image]

I'd have no doubt and I think your opinion is the same.