# There is no line here to end. What's the error?

Tags: errors, line-breaking

```
Ans7)As we can see from the automata itself that it is $\epsilon$- NFA so we need to convert it into a NFA and then to a DFA.\\
The Transition table is:\\
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
 &a&b\\
\hline
q2 &\{T,q1\}&\{q0,q1\}\\
\hline
q1 &\{q0\}&\{q0\}\\
\hline
q0 &\{q1\}&\{q1\}\\
\hline
T &$\{phi\}$&$\{\phi\}$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}\\
\end{center}
\\
```

Comment: Don't just end lines with ``\\``. Your use of ``\\`` after the `center` environment is causing the problem. Remove it. See [Documents with typical LaTeX errors](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33468/5764).

Comment: after removal also it is showing the same error..

Comment: Before the `\begin{center}` too.

Comment: Yes, I have rectified my mistake.