# Command form of tabularx (compilation problems)

Tags: tabularx

I want to change from environment form of `tabularx` to the command form but it does not compile. I need the command form because I want to use the `tabularx` inside my self defined environments later.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

% working
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l|l}
my & table
\end{tabularx}

% not working (does not compile)
\tabularx{\textwidth}{l|l}
my & table
\endtabularx

\end{document}
```

Comment: There's no reason for expecting it to work.

Comment: tabularx is not designed to be used like that so not working is the expected behaviour here,

Comment: Why is it that you would want this behavior? What result are you expecting? At this moment, there isn't really much more to say about your example, other than as `egreg` pointed out, no reason for it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tabularx` look for the end of the table, which is expected to start with `\end` (usually: `\end{tabularx}`). However, the command form can be used inside another environment:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l|X}
my & table
\end{tabularx}

\newenvironment{myenv}{%
  \tabularx{\textwidth}{l|X}%
}{%
  \endtabularx
}

\noindent
\begin{myenv}
my & table
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: The command form *should* be used in the definition of another environment, whereas the `\begin`–`\end` form cannot.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, it is wrong to use `\env` and `\endenv` in the document body, because `\begin{env}` and `\end{env}` do much more than just executing the inner commands.

Just to make a simple example, the following document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\quote
\lipsum[3]
\endquote

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

which is clearly not the expected result. Similarly,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\center
Centered text
\endcenter
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

produces the following unwanted output:

[image]

The inner commands are sometimes used *in the definition* of another environment, say

```
\newenvironment{myenum}
  {\enumerate\setlength{\itemsep}{20pt}}
  {\endenumerate}
```

because this gives better error confinement when `myenum` is not properly closed.

This is generally optional, but it becomes *mandatory* for some special environments like `tabularx` or `align`, because these environments absorb their contents before acting. So if you want to define a fixed `tabularx` specimen, you should do something like

```
\newenvironment{sptabx}
  {\par\nopagebreak\medskip\noindent\tabularx{\textwidth}{lX}}
  {\endtabularx\par\medskip}
```

so `\begin{sptabx}`, using special code in the definition of `\tabularx`, “knows” that it should look for `\end{sptabx}` as the terminator and absorb everything in between in order to pass it to for typesetting to `\endtabularx`.

Note that calling `\sptabx...\endsptabx` would *not* find `\end{sptabx}`, so there would be a mysterious error somewhere much later. The same is of course true for `\tabularx`.

A particular environment must *never* be called with the inner commands: it is `lrbox` that should always be used as

```
\begin{lrbox}{<box bin>}
...
\end{lrbox}
```

also when used in the definition of an environment.