# Why do these three changes fix this equation-numbering error?

Tags: equations, hyperref, numbering, environments

When I use `\equation`...`\endequation` instead of `\begin{equation}`...`\end{equation}`, all equations have the same number (I know this isn't best practice for environments; I'm trying to understand the underlying behavior), as in the following example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
The first equation is
\equation
  \label{pyth} a^2 + b^2 = c^2.
\endequation
The second equation is
\equation
  \label{quad} x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}.
\endequation
Referenced in order: \eqref{pyth} and \eqref{quad}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

While debugging, I've found three ways to fix it, but I have no idea why they work.

**1.** If I append `\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}` to the preamble, on my first compilation I get the error message `! Argument of \Hy@setref@link has an extra }`, but when I compile again, there's no error, and the equations are numbered correctly:

[image]

**2.** If I comment out `\usepackage{amsmath}` (and replace `\eqref` with `\ref`), the equations are numbered correctly, even without `hyperref`.

**3.** Since `\begin{`...`}` and `\end{`...`}` build a group, as mentioned in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26246/55879), I tried providing my own group:

```
The first equation is
\begingroup
\equation
  \label{pyth} a^2 + b^2 = c^2.
\endequation
\endgroup
The second equation is
% Only the first one needs to be in a group
\equation
  \label{quad} x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}.
\endequation
```

This also numbers the equations correctly, which was interesting, because I don't *a priori* know how equation numbering is related to groups.

Thus, my question is: **what differences between `\equation`...`\endequation` and `\begin{equation}`...`\end{equation}` cause these to solve this problem? Why do these solutions work?**

Comment: The difference is that you should *never* use `\equation` and `\endequation` in the body of a document.

Comment: @egreg: I realize that; this question initially arose when `\equation` and `\endequation` were part of macros that I had defined in the preamble. But I don't know why including `hyperref` or adding `\begingroup`...`\endgroup` changes anything, and would like to understand that.

Comment: saying "not best practice" isn't really the right description, it is a syntax error. The ams environments are explictly written to collect environment bodies so if the `\equation` form produces anything at all it is by accident not design.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply said, you must *never* use `\env` and `\endenv` (where `env` stands for a defined environment) in the body of the document; see [Command form of tabularx (compilation problems)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285119/command-form-of-tabularx-compilation-problems/285142#285142) for some examples.

In case `amsmath` is not loaded this *appears* to work, but you lose the important changes `amsmath` makes to the `equation` environment, fixing some weaknesses of the stock one.

Here are the kernel definitions:

```
> texdef -t latex equation endequation

\equation:
macro:->$$\refstepcounter {equation}

\endequation:
macro:->\eqno \hbox {\@eqnnum }$$\@ignoretrue
```

and here's what happens with `amsmath`:

```
> texdef -t latex -p amsmath equation endequation

\equation:
\long macro:->\incr@eqnum \mathdisplay@push \st@rredfalse \global \@eqnswtrue \mathdisplay {equation}

\endequation:
\long macro:->\endmathdisplay {equation}\mathdisplay@pop \ignorespacesafterend
```

Without the `\begin` and `\end` parts, you interfere with the `\mathdisplay@push` and `\mathdisplay@pop` functions that are vital for usage of labels, equation numbers and tags.

Another cause for failure is `\incr@eqnum`: its definition is

```
> texdef -t latex -p amsmath incr@eqnum

\incr@eqnum:
macro:->\refstepcounter {equation}\let \incr@eqnum \@empty
```

You see that, when the second `\equation` command appears, the meaning of `\incr@eqnum` is the same as `\@empty`: this is the reason why the equation number is *not* incremented. If, as expected, the macro is executed in a group, the definition of `\incr@eqnum` will be restored at group end. This should explain why in your example you get the same equation number.

When `amsmath` is loaded, `hyperref` does its changes under the assumption that local assignments are indeed local to the `equation` environment, which aren't if you don't use the `\begin{equation}`–`\end{equation}` format.

Comment: Well, TIL about `texdef`; that's really useful; thanks so much! That, combined with the change in `\incr@enum`'s behavior, is what I was confused about. Thanks!