# How to make one case equation point to another case equation?

Tags: equations, cases

I want to display the following

[image]

I'm trying to realize it with the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
        \begin{equation}
                    \begin{cases}
             &a + b\\
             & b + c
            \end{cases} \implies
            
            \begin{cases}
            & c + d\\
            & d + e
            \end{cases} 
        \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

But this gives me a lot of errors and the wrong output
[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Remove the blank line within the `equation`. Or, if you want it for aesthetic/coding reasons, insert a `%`.

Comment: See [Documents with typical LaTeX errors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33468/5764).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to getting rid of the blank line between the two `cases` environments, you should also (a) get rid of the `&` alignment operators (since you're not really making use of much of the `cases` machinery) and (b) insert a `\quad` directive after `\implies` in order to even out the spacing to the left and right of the `\implies` (aka `\Longrightarrow`) symbol.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % mathtools loads amsmath automatically
\begin{document}

        \begin{equation}
             \begin{cases}
                a + b\\
                b + c
             \end{cases} 
             \implies \quad
             \begin{cases}
                c + d\\
                d + e
            \end{cases} 
        \end{equation}

\end{document}
```